# IF Condition - Join Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to tally the number of times a term appears. Unfortunately, the terms were not well organized so a term may appear in more than one column - so I can't use just `=If(A1="HEALTH",1,0)` because `HEALTH` appears in multiple columns A, B, C etc.

I've tried nesting - `=IF(A1="HEALTH",1,IF(B2="HEALTH",1,0))` - but haven't had much success there either.

Maybe my formula's wrong? Or should I look to a different condition in Excel and if so, which?

Comment: how is you data structure like? screenshot please. first check if pnuts' answer works for you.

Comment: Your sample formula would give only 0 or 1, not the count. As per the question, it appears this is not what you want.

Comment: The possible input data you may have, and how you want to account for them, requires more detailed specification. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a case for [COUNTIF](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/). Say your data is in A1:H1:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:H1,"HEALTH")
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to count your input cells, and assuming your input data is in `A1:F1`, you may want (1)

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,"HEALTH")
```

as posted by pnuts, or (2)

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,"*HEALTH*")
```

This version also counts cells which contain `HEALTH` with other characters as well.

An alternative for formula (1) is

```
=SUM(IF(A1:F1="HEALTH",1,0))
```

entered as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Similarly for formula (2).

There are other more complex cases you may want to consider: a) cells containing `HEALTH` more than once, b) `HEALTH` only as whole word, etc.

Comment: the =COUNTIF(A1:F1,"*HEALTH*') formula was a success.